Generalized Bernoulli numbers
In Euler–Maclaurin formula Bernoulli numbers express a finite sum through the integral. In my generalization a finite sum is expressed through another finite sum with a different step. All that is needed for that is to change the generating function: instead of $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ we do the substitution $e = (1+1/n)^n$. And the generating function for generalized Bernoulli numbers is
$\frac{x}{(1+x/n)^{n}-1}$
If $n\longrightarrow \infty$ then my numbers become Bernoulli
But I couldn't find anything where my Euler–Maclaurin generalization be useful. Do you have ideas where expressing a finite sum through another finite sum with another step could be useful?

you might want to write down your formula?

It was long ago but it's easy to derive.

The following idea is a little ridiculous but maybe its worth a thought. We know that the derivative of the Prime zeta function obeys $P'(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n) \zeta'(ns)/\zeta(ns)$. Naively we might try to apply the Euler Maclaurin formula to the RHS in an attempt to define $P'(s)$ beyond its natural boundary however we have no notion of differentiating the mobius function $\mu(n)$. Your formulas instead could allow us to re-express the sum in terms of OTHER finite differences and maybe that could give some interesting insights.

And of course this same line of thinking lets us generalize to q-generalization of the euler-maclaurin (if $q$ is integral) formula etc etc... unclear if ANY of these provide useful insight but thats a family of ideas to consider

These numbers and corresponding polynomials were introduced by Korobov, see second edition of his book "Number theory methods in numerical analysis". He found some examples, where these "discrete" polynomials are more useful than "continuous" ones. They work in some boundary cases where infinite constructions do not converge.
Similar construction is also known as degenerate Bernoulli polynomials, which were introduced earlier by Carlitz.
Some related links are
On summation and interpolation formulas,
A Discrete Analog of Euler's Summation Formula
On one generalization of Stirling numbers
Korobov polynomials and umbral calculus.
For a fixed $p$, Korobov numbers $K_n$
and Korobov polynomials $K_n(x)$ can be defined via generating functions
\begin{gather}
\label{Pr_Fu_P}F_K(t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}
K_n\,\dfrac{t^n}{n!} =
\dfrac{pt}{(t+1)^p -1},\\
\label{Pr_Fu_Px}F_K(x,t)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}
K_n(x)\,\dfrac{t^n}{n!}=\dfrac{pt(t+1)^x}{(t+1)^p-1}.
\end{gather}
In particular
$$K_0=1,\quad K_1=-\dfrac{p-1}{2},\quad
K_2=\dfrac{p^2-1}{6},\quad
K_3=-\dfrac{p^2-1}{4},\\
\label{ExK} K_0(x)=1,\quad K_1(x)=x-\dfrac{p-1}{2},\quad
K_2(x)=x^2-px+\dfrac{p^2-1}{6},\\
\nonumber
K_3(x)=x^3-\dfrac{3(p+1)}{2}x^2+\dfrac{p(p+3)}{2}x-\dfrac{p^2-1}{4}.
$$
Probably the main feature of Korobov numbers and polynomials is that they connect real and $p$-adic worlds. In the real world they become close to usual Bernoulli numbers and polynomials as $p\to\infty$:
$$\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}p^{-n}K_n=B_n,\qquad\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}p^{-n}K_n(px)=B_n(x)\qquad(n\ge0).$$
If $p=0$ then Korobov numbers and polynomials coinside with
Bernoulli numbers and polynomials of the second kind
\begin{gather*}
b_0=1,\quad b_1=\dfrac{1}{2},\quad b_2=\dfrac{1}{6},\quad
b_3=\dfrac{1}{4},\\
b_0(x)=1,\quad b_1(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{2},\quad
b_2(x)=x^2-\dfrac{1}{6},\\
b_3(x)=x^3-\dfrac{3}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1}{4}.
\end{gather*}
They can be defined by generating functions
\begin{gather}
\label{Def_b}
F_b(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \frac{t^n}{n!}=\dfrac{t}{\ln(1+t)},\\
\label{Def_b(x)}F_b(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n(x)
\frac{t^n}{n!}=\dfrac{t(1+t)^x}{\ln(1+t)}.
\end{gather}
It means that $K_n(x)$ and $b_n(x)$
are close to each other in $p$-adic sense.
The same is true for corresponding Stirling numbers $\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\}_{\!p}$ and $\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right]_{\!p}$ are defined by
\begin{gather*}\label{St9}
x^{\underline{n}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\}_{\!p}p^k\left(\dfrac{x}{p}\right)^{\underline{k}},\\
\label{St10}p^n\left(\dfrac{x}{p}\right)^{\overline{n}}
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right]_{\!p}x^{\overline{k}},
\end{gather*}
where
$$\begin{array}{c}
x^{\underline{n}}=x(x-1)\ldots(x-n+1),\\
x^{\overline{n}}=x(x+1)\ldots(x+n-1).
\end{array}$$
These numbers are dual to each other
$$\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\}_{\!\frac{1}{p}}=\left(-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^{n-k}\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right]_{\!p},\qquad \left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right]_{\!\frac{1}{p}}=\left(-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^{n-k}\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\}_{\!p}\qquad(p\ne0),$$
and lie somewhere between usual Stirling numbers
\begin{align*} \label{St16}&\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\}_{0}=(-1)^{n-k}\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right],&&\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right]_{0}=(-1)^{n-k}\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\},\\
\label{St17}&\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{p^{n-k}}\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\}_{\!p}=\left\{\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right\},&&\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{p^{n-k}}\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right]_{\!p}=\left[\displaystyle{\vphantom{M}n\atop k}\right].\end{align*}

Thanks, once I tried to find something about this polinomials,  but it's hard to google a polinomial. OEIS is very good but there's nothing if you wish to know about a polinomial.

@МаратРамазанов Yes, they are not included in OEIS. I've added some information in my answer.

Seems like it’s time for the OEPS!
